# How to handle screen motion of silverlight Windows phone 7 programmatically?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

How to handle screen motion of silverlight Windows phone 7 programmatically?

Comment: what do you mean by "screen motion"? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: clearly he wants to programmatically control the motion of the handset. A tricky task, but there are some solutions to this problem ...

Answer (score 0):

The motion of the phone screen is controlled entirely by the user. Whilst the device has an accelerometer which can be used to gauge motion in all three axes, it does not have any means of powering its own motion.

I would consider a couple of solutions:

1. Modify the hardware, perhaps add propellers to the handset. Quadrocopters are a popular configuration, giving both stability and maneuverability (they can [even juggle!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3CR5y8qZf0Y))
2. If hardware modification is not an option, you are going to have to rely on the user. I would suggest displaying a large arrow indicating to the user the direction you wish to move the handset in. You can achieve this with a single arrow image using a `RotateTransform`.

Hope that help.